# Ghost Members Newsletter, subscribe new user from API

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, rest, ghost-blog

Currently generating a static website with Eleventy and I'm pulling the blog posts from the Ghost Content API. I'm hoping to use their new Members functionality to handle our newsletter updates but I noticed if I want to subscribe a new Member, I need to use Ghost Template files on the Ghost hosted pages (which I am not currently using). Wondering if there is a way to subscribe as a member via the API.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that since the members feature is experimental, there is no official documentation for it. As the given answer on the ghost forums says, I would recommend looking through the network tab on chrome or firefox and essentially reverse engineer how that API endpoint works.

I don't personally have an administrator account in my company, so I can't help further from here. Good luck!

[image: Forum Answer]